# MySQL Query Group By Date (12 hours Interval)

Tags: mysql, datetime, grafana

I wrote a sql query for getting number of users created in a period of time for plotting graph (grafana or chart js) , and my sql query is

```
 SELECT
  date(user.created_date) as "time",
  count(distinct user.id) as Number Of User,
  status as status
FROM user
WHERE
  created_date >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1649635200) AND 
  created_date < FROM_UNIXTIME(1649894399)
GROUP BY user.status, date(user.created_date)
ORDER BY date(user.created_date)
```

Here in this query created date is passed dynamically from front-end,
Now i am getting the result like,
[image]

Now whenever i select the date filter from last 24 hours/12 hours some of the result is not there,

Is there is any way to modify my sql query to group by created_date with 12 hour interval
For Example, Now query result is 11/04/2022 - 5 Users(Application Created) I want query result like this 11/04/2022 00:00:00 2 - 2 users created 11/04/2022 12:00:00 - 3 users created

Comment: You will have to split your time interval into "buckets" and then assign/compute each user creation to its corresponding bucket (e.g. AM/PM). Then you will be able to SELECT by bucket.

Comment: Did not get your point @IVOGELOV

Comment: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,565143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In grafana there is a filed `$__timeFrom()` and `$__timeTo()`
On the basis of this I rewrite my query:

```
SELECT
  (CASE 
    WHEN HOUR(TIMEDIFF($__timeFrom(), $__timeTo())) <= 24
    THEN user.created_date
    ELSE date(user.created_date) end) AS "time",
  count(distinct user.id) as Users,
FROM user
WHERE
  user.created_date >= $__timeFrom() AND 
  user.created_date < $__timeTo() AND
GROUP BY CASE
  when HOUR(TIMEDIFF($__timeFrom(), $__timeTo())) <= 24
  then user.created_date
  else date(created_date) end
ORDER BY CASE
  when HOUR(TIMEDIFF($__timeFrom(), $__timeTo())) <= 24
  then user.created_date
  else date(created_date) end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this expresion in your `GROUP BY`, you'll get a 12-hour grouping.

```sql
DATE(created_date) + INTERVAL (HOUR(created_date) - HOUR(created_date) MOD 12) HOUR
```

You can, if you have the priv, declare a stored function to make this easier to read.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TRUNC_HALFDAY$$
CREATE
  FUNCTION TRUNC_HALFDAY(datestamp DATETIME)
  RETURNS DATETIME DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
  COMMENT 'truncate to 12 hour boundary. Returns the nearest
           preceding half-day (noon, or midnight)'
  RETURN DATE(datestamp) +
                INTERVAL (HOUR(datestamp) -
                          HOUR(datestamp) MOD 12) HOUR$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can do

```sql
SELECT
  TRUNC_HALFDAY(user.created_date) as "time",
  count(distinct user.id) as Number Of User,
  status as status
FROM user
WHERE
  created_date >= whatever AND 
  created_date < whatever
GROUP BY user.status, TRUNC_HALFDAY(user.created_date)
ORDER BY TRUNC_HALFDAY(user.created_date)
```

Even though the function appears three times in your query, because it's declared `DETERMINISTIC` it only gets called once per row.

More complete writeup [here](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/).

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer And Time, i figured out the answer by using my query (in my answer) as i have to use this query in grafana for reports.